# Labels are not translated with admin integration of SonataMediaBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, sonata-media-bundle

I've added the **SonataMediaBundle** to a project I'm working on which already implements the **SonataAdminBundle**.

One thing that is strange is that, out of the box, the form/field labels aren't being translated in the admin dashboard or any of the CRUD components.

I though it was because this was a admin provided by the bundle vs an admin that I wrote, but I also have the **SonataUserBundle** integrated and the admins for those are translated just fine (using I'm assuming the `sonata.admin.label.strategy.native` strategy, which according to [this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html) is the default and should generate human readable labels)

Here's an illustration of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of un-translated labels]

And another that shows how even next to the admin exposed by inclusion of the SonataUserBundle that the translations still aren't working.

[image: Screenshot of un-translated labels on the dashboard]

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

And for version information, Here's my **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
      , "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*"
      , "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev"
      , "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*"
      , "twig/extensions": "1.0.*"
      , "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*"
      , "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
      , "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.6"
      , "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.11"
      , "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.3"
      , "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*"
      , "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.3"
      , "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "v1.1.0"
      , "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "2.3.1"
      , "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.2.3"
      , "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Framework section of **config.yml**

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

Comment: Can I see your config.yml? Did you set the **translator** and **default_locale** fields?

Comment: @Geert - Sure, I'll add it in a sec. But to give you the details here, **parameters.yml** has `locale: en` and **config.yml** has both `translator` and `default_locale` set.

Comment: So your not using the baseMediaAdmin class is this correct?

Comment: That's a good question - I'm not entirely sure how the admins for these bundles show up in the dashboard (User and Media) but something is exposing/registering them. I don't specifically define them in **app/Resources/config/admin.yml**

Comment: I read your question wrong.. Thought you said you wrote a custom admin for it... I also have no idea since he's using the internal admin provided by the media bundle which should work. Maybe it's because of the older version of your bundle? Any possibility you can upgrade it to a higher version?

Comment: @GeertWille That was it! I didn't realize how out-of-date the media bundle was. I stumbled a couple times getting it upgraded, but now I'm on 2.2.8 and it worked. If you post this as an answer I'll gladly upvote it and give you the credit

Comment: I added it as an answer ;) Glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try and upgrade your media bundle since your using an outdated version. Your using a branch that has his last change 7 months ago so if I was you I considered upgrading to **2.2.8** and that'll hopefully fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to clear cache files. Translations files need the cache to be cleared once generated.